# PHP oneliner to check for alphanumeric + -, _ and

Tags: php, filter

I need simple one liner to check for alphanumeric characters with -, _ and . (for filenames), to be used as an if condition.

I tried several things, including ctype_allnum and preg match, but I can't get it to work. For example:

```
if(!ctype_alnum(preg_replace("-_\.", "", "should_pas-s.html")))
{ sth; }
```

I know about ctype_alnum, but that takes external (not in one line) array, so it would complicate things. (There are many conditions to check.)

Comment: What do you mean by `I can't get it to work` ? What's the result ? And what do you mean by `ctype_alnum [...] takes external [...] array` ? It takes a string and returns a bool.

Comment: I would like to put everything into one like to fit and work inside the IF. With this:

`$a = 'my_filename01.html';
$b = array('-', '_', '.');

if(!ctype_alnum(str_replace($b, '', $a))) {
    echo 'not ok';
} 

else {echo "all fine";}`
it complicates things.

Comment: OK, and what doesn't work with your attempt `ctype_alnum(preg_replace("-_\.", "", "should_pas-s.html")` ? Is `preg_replace` doing what you expect ? And `ctype_alnum` ?

Comment: I get "No ending delimiter '-'" with preg.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: preg\_replace(): No ending delimiter '/' found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164229/warning-preg-replace-no-ending-delimiter-found)

Comment: OK. Your issue is with your pattern, I answer with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is with the usage of [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php). The documentation tells a bit about what the pattern should look like.

You need to put begin and end delimiter in your regular expression. For example:

```
preg_replace("#-_\.#", "", "should_pas-s.html")
```

so in your case the code should be:

```
if(!ctype_alnum(preg_replace("#-_\.#", "", "should_pas-s.html")))
```

This is already answered in this question:
[Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '/' found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164229/warning-preg-replace-no-ending-delimiter-found)

Or this one:
[What Delimiter to use for preg_replace in PHP (replace working outside of PHP but not inside)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322718/what-delimiter-to-use-for-preg-replace-in-php-replace-working-outside-of-php-bu)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was searching for this error, but didn't find anythign.